# How to check if a user has Full Control in a current web in SharePoint using J query?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, office365api, sharepoint-2016

Is there a Rest Api or any other function that can tell if a user with certain login name has full control in a particular web. 
I am trying to check if a user has full control in a web using jquery or rest api. 
Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use

```
    function getUserRoles(webUrl,accountName)
   {
    return getUserEffectivePermissions(webUrl,accountName).then(function(data){
    var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data);
    var permLevels = [];
    for(var permLevelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
        if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(permLevelName)) {
           var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(permLevelName);
           if(permissions.has(permLevel)){
              permLevels.push(permLevelName);
            }
        }     
    }
    return permLevels;
   });   
 }
```